# Proof of the Schwarz's inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space where dot product is defined. Then the following is true:
>   $$\forall x, y\in V \quad \langle x,y\rangle^2  \leq \langle x,x \rangle\langle y,y \rangle$$
>   **Proof:**
>
> Consider the following linear combination: $z=\langle x,y\rangle x - \langle x,x\rangle y$. Let's find the dot product $\langle z,z\rangle \ge 0$: 
>   $$\langle z,z\rangle = \langle \langle x,y\rangle x - \langle x,x\rangle y,\langle x,y\rangle x - \langle x,x\rangle y\rangle\\
> \stackrel{?}= \langle x,x\rangle \left[ \langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle - \langle x,y\rangle^2\right] \ge0.
> $$

This is a proof from my linear algebra course book. I fail too see how the transition which I marked with $?$ was made. I will appreciate a clear explanation.

Comment: Did you try going from the previous step, doing the operations, and then simplifying? You'll get the same result

Comment: @m1cky22 yes I tried but still don't see how they get the result

Comment: If this isn't answered by the time I get home from work then I'll try to show it.

Comment: Write the coefficients as $a$ and $b$ instead of $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle x,x\rangle$. What is $\langle ax-by,ax-by\rangle$? Then substitute back in what $a$ and $b$ are, and simplify.

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand they factor out $\langle x,x\rangle$, but still don't get it with your sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from using the bilinearity of the inner product:

1. $\langle \lambda a,b \rangle = \lambda \langle a,b \rangle$,
2. $\langle a, \lambda b\rangle = \lambda \langle a,b \rangle$,
3. $\langle a+c,b \rangle = \langle a,b \rangle + \langle c,b \rangle$, and
4. $\langle a,b +c\rangle = \langle a,b \rangle + \langle a,bc\rangle$.

Using these to break up the inner product, we find

\begin{align*}
\langle z,z\rangle &= \langle\langle x,y\rangle x, \langle x,y\rangle x - \langle x,x \rangle y \rangle - \langle  \langle x,x \rangle y, \langle x,y\rangle x - \langle x,x \rangle y\rangle\\
 &= \langle x,y\rangle\langle x, \langle x,y\rangle x - \langle x,x \rangle y \rangle - \langle x,x \rangle\langle  y, \langle x,y\rangle x - \langle x,x \rangle y\rangle\\\
 &= \langle x,y\rangle\langle x, \langle x,y\rangle x\rangle -\langle x,y \rangle\langle x, \langle x,x\rangle y \rangle - \langle x,x \rangle\langle  y, \langle x,y\rangle x\rangle + \langle x,x\rangle \langle y,\langle x,x \rangle y\rangle\\
&= \langle x,y\rangle^2\langle x,x\rangle - \langle x,y\rangle^2\langle x,x\rangle - \langle x,y \rangle^2 \langle x,x\rangle + \langle x,x \rangle^2 \langle y,y\rangle\\
&= \langle x,x \rangle (-\langle x,y\rangle^2 + \langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y \rangle)
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Perfect, now it's clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In general we have:

$0\leq\left\langle a\mathbf{x}-b\mathbf{y},a\mathbf{x}-b\mathbf{y}\right\rangle =a^{2}\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle -2ab\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle +b^{2}\left\langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle $.

Now substitute $a=\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle $
and $b=\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle $ to find:

$0\leq\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle ^{2}\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle -2\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle \left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle \left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle +\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle ^{2}\left\langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle =\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle \left[\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle \left\langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle -\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle ^{2}\right]$.

Since $\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle \geq0$ we
are allowed to conclude that:

$0\leq\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle \left\langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle -\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle ^{2}$

---

Alternative proof:

For every scalar $\lambda$ we have:

$0\leq\left\langle \lambda\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y},\lambda\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\right\rangle $

The RHS equalizes $\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle \lambda^{2}+2\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle \lambda+\left\langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle $
and this quadratic form in $\lambda$ can only satisfy the condition
if its discrimant does not exceed $0$.

This leads to:

$\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle ^{2}\leq\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle \left\langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle $